# NUnit - Monodevelop Integration

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, monodevelop

when I'd like to start a unittest within Monodevelop 2.6 (Ubuntu default repository) and NUnit-Integration (apt-get install monodevelop-nunit), I get always the following error.

Even if I compile my projects as .Net 3.5 (x86) or .Net 4.0 (Any CPU) or any other combination, I get the following error.

I do not understand this because 'nunit-console BurnSystems.Tests.dll' is working perfectly.

This would be perfectly OK, but I need the debugger to check where the root cause for a failed test is. "Debug external application" like in Visual Studio seems not to be available in MonoDevelop.

---

```
Error - 20:45:31 - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Server stack trace: 
  at NUnit.Util.DomainManager.CreateDomain (NUnit.Core.TestPackage package) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.NUnit.External.ExternalTestRunner.GetRunner (System.String assemblyPath) [0x00000] in :0 
  at MonoDevelop.NUnit.External.ExternalTestRunner.Run (IRemoteEventListener listener, ITestFilter filter, System.String path, System.String suiteName, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 supportAssemblies) [0x00000] in :0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices:InternalExecute (System.Reflection.MethodBase,object,object[],object[]&)
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.InternalExecuteMessage (System.MarshalByRefObject target, IMethodCallMessage reqMsg) [0x00000] in :0 

Exception rethrown at [0]: 

  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke (System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy rp, IMessage msg, System.Exception& exc, System.Object[]& out_args) [0x00000] in :0
```